# How to get rootView on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm developing an app that needs to take a screenshot of a line of my adapter and this need to get the layout base of the adapter.

How to do this?

I'm want to print this view:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#getChildAt(int)) but it only returns views that are attached to the recyclerview.